# Why wasn't CSS designed with parent selectors from the beginning?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Based on the initial drafts of the CSS4 spec, [parent selectors will finally be available in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/). My question is, why didn't the W3C include this in an earlier CSS spec? Why didn't it get published along with the rest of CSS's selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off: what you're referring to from Selectors 4 is not just a "parent selector". It's a [*subject selector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#subject). This means it doesn't just involve a combinator that points from one selector to another and says "this is that's parent", similar to the child combinator `>`. It entails syntax that says "this particular element is the one that will receive the styles", namely, the subject of the selector. This is why you see the use of something like a prefix or a suffix, rather than a combinator. You just *happen* to be able to use it to *select the parent of an element*; but it wasn't designed with that functionality alone in mind. That's why it's inappropriate to just call it a "parent selector".

And the syntax for a subject selector is incredibly hard to get right. They've been at this for more than 10 years, mind you; just search the [public mailing list archives](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style) for "subject selector", and you'll find stuff that dates back to 1999 (!), when CSS 2.0 had just become a W3C Recommendation. Even in the current Selectors 4 drafts, they haven't yet decided on a final syntax: the FPWD from 2011 had it use a `$` sign, and in the 2012 WD it's now a `!`.

As for parent selectors in general: this has historically<sup>1</sup> mostly been an issue with repainting performance from what I've seen. Browsers construct the DOM sequentially as a page gets downloaded, and CSS is applied immediately in real time *as the page loads*. With a parent selector, a browser must wait until its children are known before it can decide whether to apply its rule. This can cause repainting issues, especially on slow page loads, leading further to a detriment in user experience.

This isn't a problem with descendant, child or following sibling selectors because they follow the natural source order of a document, particularly in a declarative markup language like HTML.

That's one of the biggest among several concerns, I imagine, that have prevented parent selectors from making the cut. In fact, in the *very* beginning, CSS1 didn't even have child or sibling selectors; it only had a descendant selector, which itself wasn't even called that; it was known simply as [contextual selection](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#contextual-selectors), which was a very primitive concept back in the day when CSS had just spawned from the development hell that was presentational markup.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Now that Selectors 4 introduces a way to apply rules to any individual element represented in a complex selector, you'd wonder if those performance concerns have been addressed or have otherwise been made irrelevant, since the selector as a whole would still have to depend on a complete structure in order for a browser to determine a match, and that means page load remains a major factor. Unfortunately, that's off limits for me; I don't implement CSS so I can't speak for implementation issues.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

CSS was designed to applied in a forward-only fashion, so that the styles applicable to an element are known as soon as the source for that element is downloaded.

Parent selectors break that design, since the renderer cannot know whether it applies to an element until all of the elements children are downloaded from the server.